# A good way to do multiple "layers" for a 2D map

Tags: java

So this idea popped into my head after I played "Awesomenauts".

The map in Awesomenauts consists of multiple layers, the backdrop or background, a "foreground", the "middle?" layer, and "top" layer.

I was wondering what is the best way to do this efficiently?

I thought up of something like this:

```
public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<LayerObject>> map;
```

And the keys used for the hash map would be used to access the assigned layers which would be constants:

```
public static final int BACKDROP = 0;
public static final int FOREGROUND = 1;
```

And to render them in order, I'd loop through the hash map and then loop through each array list of the layer objects or layers.

Is this a good way to approach this or no?

Comment: Why a HashMap rather than a simple ArrayList for the layers themselves if the indexes start at 0 and go up sequentially anyway?

Comment: You need to render each layer and its layer objects in order; so it actually acts for its purpose. Using a single ArrayList won't do it because then you'd have to sort it by let's say the layer objects ID.